# Qual è il significato di "serrato" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel romanzo *Rinascimento privato* di Maria Bellonci ho letto:

> Da due mesi Giulio Secondo era entrato in Bologna dopo aver cacciato i Bentivoglio abbandonati dai francesi loro alleati; si restituiva così alla Chiesa quella terra opulenta di beni e di importanza strategica. L'impresa aveva avuto un esito improvviso tanto che il mio Francesco, nominato con ogni magnificenza Luogotenente dell'esercito papale, inutilmente era corso alla presa di Bologna perché i Bentivoglio se n'erano fuggiti senza attendere il confronto delle armi. Come accade, la vittoria non risolveva niente, l'intrigo politico rimaneva **serrato**. Dalla Francia giungeva notizia che re Luigi aveva stabilito di scendere in Italia a conquistare Genova con dubbi pretesti di antiche attribuzioni.

Ho cercato il termine "serrato" in alcuni dizionari, ma non capisco il suo significato in questo brano. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: L'aggettivo *serrato* è il participio passato di *serrare*, cioè *chiudere*. Un *ritmo serrato* è incalzante (puoi trovare altri significati figurati sul [Treccani](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/serrato1/)). Probabilmente l'autrice intende *non sciolto*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nel passaggio da te indicato ***serrato*** vuole figurativamente significare **incalzante**, **stringente**, **concitato**.

È un termine mutuato dal gergo militare e stava ad indicare quando l'esercito avanzava in ordine chiuso e compatto nell'imminenza della battaglia o per paura di essere assalito in imboscata.

La vittoria non aveva portato la pace, anzi, le manovre politiche, i sotterfugi continuavano come se nulla fosse cambiato e i contendenti erano in continuo assetto da guerra.

Comment: Terrei in conto anche la possibilità che ci sia un gioco di significati legato a "intrigo" (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/intrigo/), che ha in sé il senso di intrico, intreccio. Tale intreccio, dunque, rimane chiuso, stretto, non sciolto, come suggeriva @egreg (subito prima si dice che «la vittoria non risolveva», con "risolvere" che richiama "sciogliere", "slegare").